# Styling JQuery Mobile Themes

Tags: jquery, android, css, mobile

I am working on Android app using PhoneGap and JQM 1.0b2.  My question spans both the JQM Themes as well as CSS.  In android (as well as iPhone) native apps have very very nice looking glossy title bars/headers, as well as complementing toolbars /button bars.

Does anyone have an example of CSS showing a "wet" gradient which looks like the glossy controls of native apps?   Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that you can work something out with this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

..and you can always throw some water at your screen to make it look even more wet. 
( Though I dont take any responsibility if your screen says bye bye. )